# What does "written off as junk" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **11. Am I making it easy for the customer to respond?**
>   [...]
>   Small inaccuracies in job title and department (not to mention surname!) are behind a huge percentage of communications **written off as junk**. When all you had to do was allow them to update a word...
>   <sub>Source: [Email Marketing - 12 Tips to Help You Conquer Your Direct Marketing Campaign Challenges : MarketingProfs Article](http://www.marketingprofs.com/articles/2014/26439/12-tips-to-help-you-conquer-your-direct-marketing-campaign-challenges)</sub>

What does written off as junk mean here?

Comment: To *write something off as X* means to assign it to the category "X", which by implication is a *worthless* category. That's because ***to write off [something]*** comes from accountancy contexts where it means *to value something at **zero** [in the company accounts]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does written off as junk mean here?

> *Small inaccuracies in job title and department (not to mention surname!) are behind a huge percentage of communications **written off as junk**.*

It means that such communications will be thought of as worthless by your customers. Why? Because you wrote their job titles, or departments, or even their surnames wrong! According to the article, such errors are behind a huge percentage of such ineffective communications.

---

Here are relevant definitions in Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[write off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/write-off)**
>   <sup>phrasal verb</sup>
>   2 *[transitive]* to decide that someone or something will not succeed and so to stop giving them your attention and energy
>   *He thought the teachers had written him off.*
>   [...]
>   4 *[transitive]* to say that something is not worth anything, for example a machine used to make something
>   *After five years you can write the equipment off for tax.*

Next time you feel like you're unable to make sense of a verb and see that it's used with (what look like) a preposition, try looking up for a combination of such "*verb* + *preposition*". Chances are you will find that it's a phrasal verb. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. what dose the last sentence mean "are behind a huge percentage of such ineffective communications"

Comment: It means that such inaccuracies (in job title and department, surname, etc.) are one of the main reasons behind the communication failure. (It's the same thing the article means by the phrase "a huge percentage of communications written off as junk".)